# Global screen created from pushGlobalScreen() not working with popScreen() (Blackberry)

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me

I'm using `pushGlobalScreen()` to create a global screen from the background of an app, but I cannot remove the global screen once it has been created.

Here's my code from my Listener:

```
UiApplication.getUiApplication().requestForeground();
UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushGlobalScreen(new QuestionGScreen(), 1, UiApplication.GLOBAL_QUEUE);
```

The QuestionGScreen has some simple buttons with that then creates another global screen using the same code (minus the requestForeground) if yes is pressed, and if no is pressed then I have

```
UiApplication.getUiApplication().requestBackground();
UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen();
```

I know that `popScreen()` with no arguments is depreciated, but using `popScreen()` with
`UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen()` gives me an illegal argument exception.

Is there some other way to remove global screens, or am I doing something wrong with popping the global screen off?

Thanks, Quinn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Global screens are not managed by the BlackBerry as part of the Application, like a PopupupScreen or a ordinary screen.  As a result, when you push a Global screen it can not be found on the Application Display stack, nor will it be "background"ed when the Application is put in the background.

If you wish to interact with a Global Screen once you have pushed it, you will have to retain a reference to the screen yourself.

Remember when interacting with a Dialog screen (for example if you are processing a Button press), you will not be executing in your own Applications context, because the screen is not running in your own context.  So to interact with your application I recommend that you try Global Events.  You will find a good article on these here:

[Global Events article](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Global-Events-and-Global-Event-Listeners/ta-p/444814)

Personally I would avoid using Global Screens unless you really need to bring something to the attention of the user regardless of what they are currently doing - imagine your user is in the middle of some important email, does he or she really need to see your screen?  Try some other form of notification.

Can you achieve what you want with a normal popup screen?  Note that global screens are not special, the global screens are just pushed differently.

**Update**

You made this comment: "the screens disappear when the phone call screen is closed"

I must apologise, this triggered me to review your original post in which you said (which I missed) "Here's my code from my Listener".

The problem here is that in fact, your listener code is running in the context of the phone application.  Now the phone application will put itself into the background when the phone call is over.  This is, I think, why your popup screens were disappearing.  And of course the global ones do not since they are not part of the phone application.

Accepted practice in listeners is to do as little processing as possible in them, instead switch contexts to your own application using a Global Event (see link earlier). Your app will be running in the background, will receive the Global Event, will display the popup screen, but to see the popup screen, you will have to requestForeground(), which will hide the phone screen.  Not a big deal, since that screen is going to hide itself anyway...

Comment: I have done what you mentioned in your last point and changed the screen to a simple popup screen, but I am encountering a problem where when the popup shows up, I can navigate though the links (yes and no buttons) but all screen spawned from the popup will disappear within around 3 seconds. Is there an argument I have to pass to not have the screens disappear so fast? Thank you very much for your help so far as well.

Comment: Actually, I think I found the error, the screens disappear when the phone call screen is closed. I'm going to try and find what event is thrown when the phone call screen is closed rather than when the call is ended and use that instead.

Comment: Excellent! I've managed to set up the global events to work the way you said and it runs very smoothly! I'm sure there's still some bugs laying around, but the core functionality is there. Thank you very much for your help!